# Calling Async method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying calling the async method `SendParkInfo` method using the `await` operator like this

`await Task.WhenAny(parkList);`and `await Task.WhenAny(parkInfo);`

`parkInfo` has `SendParkInfo` method object

Here is some part of my code.

```
    public async Task<AvailableParksResponse> GetAvailableParks(IEnumerable<string> parkRegionList)
    {
    //
        var parkList = parkRegionList.Select(x => SendParkInfo(x)).ToList();
        var parkListTask = await Task.WhenAny(parkList);
        response.ParkInfoList = new List<Task<ParkInfo>> { parkListTask };

        var parkInfo = SendParkInfo(id);
        var parkTask = await Task.WhenAny(parkInfo);
        response.ParkInfo = new List<Task<ParkInfo>> { parkTask };

    //
    }

    public virtual async Task<ParkInfo> SendParkInfo(string id) 
    {
    //
        var apiResponse = await apiClient.GetAsync(RequestUri + id);
    //
    }
```

Is it ok to call `SendParkInfo` like the way I am calling and then using `await` operator with `Task.WhenAny` method. Or is there any better way of calling the `Async SendParkInfo` method

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There seem to be some compilation issues here. You are trying to redefine `IEnumerable<string> parkList` as an `IList<Task<ParkInfo>>`, is that intentional?

Comment: @NathanTaylor sorry I misunderstood your question. response.ParkInfoList is like this   public IEnumerable<Task<ParkInfo>> ParkInfo { get; set; }

Comment: Your example is just too sparse. Where does id in GetAvailableParks come from? How is AvailableParksResponse used? How does it make sense to have list of parks, but only return the first one that completes?

Comment: `Task.WhenAny()` expects a collection of tasks, but you are using it with a single `Task<ParkInfo>`, passing it the result of `SendParkInfo(id)`.

Comment: Why you need to use WhenAny? You can not await on SendParkInfo?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya then i get the error cannot convert from 'ParkInfo' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ParkInfo>'

Comment: @NathanTaylor so it is fine with this collection parkRegionList.Select(x => SendParkInfo(x)).ToList()  ?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed that first usage appears to be correct, but the designation is a bit confusing. The result of `await Task.WhenAny(List<Task>)` will be a `Task` (not a task list). On the next line `response.ParkInfoList` will not compile because the input is not a `Task<ParkInfo>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.WhenAny()` will return a `Task` which is considered completed when at least one item in the list of tasks passed into `WhenAny()` has completed. This usually an appropriate option if you want to return data incrementally, as processing completes.

Alternatively, if your intent is to only return a result when all async tasks have completed, consider `Task.WhenAll()`.